# Syntax sugar for pointer-to-member works for array but not std::vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdvector, dereference, pointer-to-member

I wrote some sample code (below) to understand C++'s *pointer-to-member* feature. However, I've come across a strange issue wherein the syntax

```
(*it).*attribute
```

is accepted by the compiler, but the syntax

```
it->*attribute
```

is not accepted, with the error

> left hand operand to `->*` must be a pointer to class compatible with the right hand operand, but is `std::__1::__wrap_iter<Bowl *>`

However, if I uncomment `Bowl bowls[3] =` and comment out `std::vector<Bowl> bowls =`, i.e. switch from using `std::vector` to using a primitive array, then both syntaxes work correctly.

From the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access), I found

> The expression `E1->*E2` is exactly equivalent to `(*E1).*E2` for built-in types

so it seems that the error has something to do with the fact that arrays are built-in types but `std::vector` is not. Later in that section, I found

> In overload resolution against user-defined operators, for every combination of types D, B, R, where class type B is either the same class as D or an unambiguous and accessible base class of D, and R is either an object or function type, the following function signature participates in overload resolution:
>
> ```
> R& operator->*(D*, R B::*);
> ```

but as `std::vector` does not define `operator->*` I am very confused. Why do I get this error on one syntax but not the other, and only when using `std::vector` instead of a primitive array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class Bowl
{
public:
  unsigned int apples;
  unsigned int oranges;
  unsigned int bananas;

  Bowl(unsigned int apples, unsigned int oranges, unsigned int bananas)
    : apples(apples), oranges(oranges), bananas(bananas)
  {
    // nothing to do here
  }
};

template <typename TClass, typename TIterator, typename TResult>
TResult sum_attribute(TIterator begin, TIterator end, TResult TClass::*attribute)
{
  TResult sum = 0;
  for (TIterator it = begin; it != end; ++it)
  {
    sum += (*it).*attribute;
    sum += it->*attribute;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Bowl> bowls =
  // Bowl bowls[3] =
    {
      {1, 2, 3},
      {4, 5, 6},
      {7, 8, 9},
    };

  int num_apples = sum_attribute(std::begin(bowls), std::end(bowls), &Bowl::apples);
  int num_oranges = sum_attribute(std::begin(bowls), std::end(bowls), &Bowl::oranges);
  int num_bananas = sum_attribute(std::begin(bowls), std::end(bowls), &Bowl::bananas);

  std::cout << "We have " << num_apples << " apples, " << num_oranges << " oranges, and " <<
    num_bananas << " bananas. Now wasn't that fun?" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `(*it).*attribute` calls overloaded `operator*`, and then applies built-in pointer-to-member access operator `.*` to the result. `it->*attribute` doesn't work because it's not possible to overload `->*` operator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thought you could overload `operator ->*` but not `operator .*` - am I mistaken?

Comment: @templatetypedef Upon closer inspection, indeed you you could; but iterators normally don't.

Comment: It seems `.*` and `->*` don't actually have names in the standard (they're both under the section "Pointer-to-member operators" but without further naming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To better understand this, I think it's helpful to talk about the parallels to the `*` and `->` operators.

If you have an iterator of class type and you write

```
(*itr).field
```

C++ interprets it to mean

```
itr.operator*().field
```

Similarly, if you write

```
itr->field
```

C++ interprets it to mean

```
itr.operator->().field
```

Notice that these are calling different overloaded operators. The first one calls `operator*`, and the second calls `operator->`. This is different than built-in types; as you noted, for built-in types the syntax

```
base->field
```

is just a shorthand for

```
(*base).field
```

There's something similar going on here when you talk about

```
(*itr).*memberPtr
```

and

```
itr->*memberPtr
```

In the first case, C++ treats `(*itr).*memberPtr` to mean

```
itr.operator*().*memberPtr
```

Notice that this means that the `.*` operator is being applied directly to the item being iterated over and that the iterator itself isn't overloading the `.*` operator. On the other hand, if you write

```
itr->*memberPtr
```

C++ treats it as a call to

```
itr.operator->*(memberPtr)
```

and reports an error because iterator types aren't required to - and rarely do - implement `operator ->*`. (In fact, I've seen exactly zero overloads of `operator ->*` in the course of programming in C++).

The fact that primitive types treat `base->*memberPtr` as `(*base).*memberPtr` here is irrelevant, the same reason that the fact that primitive types treat `base->field` as `(*base).field`; the compiler will not automatically generate `operator*` from `operator->` or vice-versa.

There's a separate question about why iterators aren't required to do this, and that's something I don't have a good answer to, unfortunately. My guess is that this is a sufficiently rare case that no one thought to put it in the standard, but I'm not sure.

As for why this works for primitive arrays but not `std::vector`, primitive arrays you're working with raw pointers, which support the `->*` operator. The iterators for `std::vector` aren't required to be raw pointers, and if they're objects of class type, the above reasoning explains why you shouldn't expect them to support `operator ->*`.

Comment: Beautiful answer. This makes perfect sense; thank you.